# bash: ./start.sh: Permission denied && ./start.sh: line 64: .//WrightEagle: Permission denied

Tags: permissions

hi I wanna to start my sever and my game to rcsoocersim but when I want to start the game and write in terminal ./start.sh 
bash: ./start.sh: Permission denied
I try and write chmod 700 *sh or chmod +x *sh and the result was

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> WrightEagle Goalie: 1
./start.sh: line 58: .//WrightEagle: Permission denied
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> WrightEagle Player: 2
./start.sh: line 64: .//WrightEagle: Permission denied
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> WrightEagle Player: 3
./start.sh: line 64: .//WrightEagle: Permission denied
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> WrightEagle Player: 4
./start.sh: line 64: .//WrightEagle: Permission denied
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> WrightEagle Player: 5
./start.sh: line 64: .//WrightEagle: Permission denied
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> WrightEagle Player: 6
./start.sh: line 64: .//WrightEagle: Permission denied
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> WrightEagle Player: 7
./start.sh: line 64: .//WrightEagle: Permission denied
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> WrightEagle Player: 8
./start.sh: line 64: .//WrightEagle: Permission denied
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> WrightEagle Player: 9
./start.sh: line 64: .//WrightEagle: Permission denied
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> WrightEagle Player: 10
./start.sh: line 64: .//WrightEagle: Permission denied
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> WrightEagle Player: 11
./start.sh: line 64: .//WrightEagle: Permission denied
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> WrightEagle Coach
./start.sh: line 71: .//WrightEagle: Permission denied
```

Plz any help could be greatful tnx

Answer (score 1):

You need to `chmod` the WrightEagle file like this:

```
chmod u+x .//WrightEagle
```